# Why shoud we add different versions of the same family of font files like (light, bold ,black or italic...)?

Tags: flutter, fonts

For example, I found that even without adding the bold version of the Raleway font, I can set `fontWeight: FontWeight.bold` and that works correctly. So why we add bold and black versions of fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add fontWeight: FontWeight.bold to a regular font say, like Raleway font, you get a faux style which is not the correct style (boldness) of what the font should actually look like when you use its 'bold' or 'black' versions. It could potentially lead to double boldness and is not the true representation.

You should check out google font package on pub.dev https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts
 I use the package to avoid the hassle of adding my fonts manually.

Comment: some google fonts don't have all the styles